# How can I resolve the problem of organization policy in my Microsoft GitHub acount?

Tags: github

[image]

This is the message that I get:

> You may not create private repositories by organization policy.

I did not try anything, because I don't understand well the problem.

Comment: Warm welcome to SO. Please try to use correct upper case letters, e.g. in the beginning of your title, sentences or the word "I". This would be gentle to your readers. Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Then update your question with code to show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue today, and I tried to create a private repository in my own account, not within the organization I am a member of. However, when I switched to the other account and then back to my own, the option "Private" was suddenly visible. So it might be an issue of turning it off and on again ...

Comment: logging out and then re-logging in solved the problem for me (I was working from my personal mobile phone)

Comment: You are right, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Was facing same issue so tried searching and ended up here, read official docs but got nothing, so refreshed the page and tried again and now the option was visible.

No idea what changed but trying refreshing the page or opening it in new tab/window.

If that too does not work try re-logging and clearing cache.

Note: this is for my personal account where I'm not part of any organization.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today too, but it seems to be back just like before, maybe a deployment has gone wrong on github side ‍♂️ (i'm not part of an organization either from my personnal account

[image]